# CSV кодировка символов

Tags: c#, excel, csv, cp1251

Имеются строки, которые содержат символы "'¬', '∧', '∨', '→', '⇔',". 
При использовании `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fstream);` т.е. без указания кодировки, открывая в Excel'e получаю следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее попробовал `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fstream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));` т.е. указать кодировку, в результате получил следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат хоть и лучше, но символы все еще корректно не отображаются.
Возможно ли записать данные символы в CSV формате с корректным отображением?

Comment: Как вариант попробовать Unicode

Comment: BOM не забудте, с# по-умолчанию вроде её ставит, если не поставит - проверьте что б была.

Comment: 'cp1251' - вы все еще работаете в Windows XP ? Здрасти новый год, все уже давно юникодом пользуются.